# fastest method to query values by row keys in hbase

Tags: hbase

faster method to query the rows in hbase that row-keys are in rowKeys?

rowKeys is an array like:

```
rowKeys=[1,2,4,5,6,34,223,113]
```

*(like sql in)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can build your `IN` clause as a [FilterList](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html) of [RowFilter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RowFilter.html)'s - with `MUST_PASS_ONE` flag.

See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971955/query-hbase-table-by-key-using-rowfilter-not-working).